# How to use existing staff to define their features theirselves?

Tags: 2010, infopath, personalization

I have a MOSS that staff already entered. I am creating an app about defining features of staff. Now i can define this features by myself as admin.

But i want my staff to define their features by themselves. 
I googled something but i really dont know what to do or what to search. 
Where should i begin to search ?

Answer (score 0):

Again I am answering my question (:

Anyway,

I did this via userName() function at Infopath.
I get user Id via this function and using this i can get the person. After I have person
I added an action to disable person picker. And I really solved that.

Regards